# LD_PRELOAD to override functions from dynamically loaded library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen, ld-preload

I'm using a wrapper library to trace functions using `LD_PRELOAD` which does work when the functions I'm tracing are referenced in the application.

The wrapper library uses `dlsym` to populate symbols it wraps.

But this is not working if the application doesn't reference functions directly but through `dlopen`.
Should the wrapper library work with dynamically loaded libraries? If not, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: May be some details about the flags passed to dlopen() and dlsym() would help to narrow down the pb ? Please, share an example of symbol wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this is not working if the application doesn't reference functions directly but through dlopen.

If the application performs:

```
void *h = dlopen("libfoo.so", ...);
void *sym = dlsym(h, "symbol");
```

then the `symbol` will be resolved to `libfoo.so`, regardless of any `LD_PRELOAD`s (and indeed regardless of any other instances of `symbol` in other already loaded libraries). This is working as intended.

> Should the wrapper library work with dynamically loaded libraries?

No.

> If not, is there a way to make it work?

Yes, you can make it work. You would need to provide a `replacement.so` which provides *all* the symbols which the application looks up in `libfoo.so`, and then make it so the `replacement.so` is `dlopend()ed` by the application.

One way to do that is to rename `libfoo.so` -> `libfoo.so.orig`, copy `replacement.so` -> `libfoo.so`, and have `replacement.so` itself `dlopen("libfoo.so.orig", ...)`.

If the application `dlopen`s `libfoo.so` without absolute path, you may be able to arrange so `replacement.so` is earlier in the search path, e.g.

```
mkdir /tmp/replacement
ln -s /path/to/replacement.so /tmp/replacement/liboo.so
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/replacement /path/to/a.out
```

If you go that route, `replacement.so` would still need to know how to `dlopen` the original `libfoo.so` (could use hard-coded absolute path for that).